# How to Communicate With a Program Through Console / C++

Tags: c++, console

When I run an application through a console, for example, `$application start`, how can I communicate with said application? So I can for example do `$application load --/home/application/files/file.txt --warn=0 --notice=0` and that running instance of the application would react to this...

I do not want to keep listening to the console on the application side. I want to be able to close the console, reopen it, and still interact with the program.

The reason why I am doing this is because I want a master program that loads in different operations which it performs in the background. I want to be able to add operators, and remove operations.

Myself I have some experience with PHP and I know Apache has such behavior.

**EDIT:** After some comments of you guys, I concluded that I am required to use IPC. I have heard of this before but I never really understood how it works. After some Googling and the WikiPedia links you showed me I concluded that there are a sh-t tun of ways of handling IPC.  I want to send packages of data to the main process, which one would be the best in my case?  My personal favorite atm is a message queue but that only seems to work within the same process.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Linux, preferably as many distros as possible. I'm using Ubuntu but it's aimed at server versions.

Comment: Too many possible answers. See [Inter-Process Communication (IPC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) for a place to start.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: Given the users experience that is overkill. There are much easier techniques that you can start with to get things working.

Comment: It's not entirely trivial. First you need to identify that the other instance is running - most programs do that by storing a "pid-file". Then the "commands" are generally passed via some sort of IPC mechanism (a named pipe, perhaps?)

Comment: @MatsPetersson My idea was to send a signal to that program and than wait for 2 responses back. One saying the program is indeed running, and a second one saying the action has been successfully executed, or failed of course. Your way seems a bit better though. (No weird timers waiting for a signal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to be able to *run application in background* and have ability to close console where it was started, you may use `nohup` utility. then first instance of you app should create some ("well known") IPC resource (message queue, FIFO, whatever), so further instances will communicate over it with the first instance.

and it will be relatively easy, then to turn you app into a full functional *daemon*.

Answer (score 1):

Since @LokiAstari pointed out, that you may don't have much experience with C++, I would recommend you to read: [How to parse command line parameters](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/DEN36Up4/).

I would then use a temporary file in `/tmp` to communicate with the main program, which run an infinite loop, waiting for modifications to the temporary file.

Comment: I know how to parse a command line, and I will need this to send the signal to the main instance of the program. My question was, how do I get that signal there.

Comment: So this would be referred to as a "Named Pipe"?

Comment: The problem is, how would I handle a response from the 'daemon' to the process writing to the file? Having another file might cause trouble if there are 2 consoles sending a message at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would do this in multiple stages.
As otherwise you are going to be trying to solve to many different problems at once.

What you are doing is writing a service (a long running application). Communication with the service by running a command usually involves running a different application that talks to the service (in apaches case the apache command starts the `httpd` service. Then subsequent commands talk to the `httpd` service).

But to get this up and running it is easier to go through a few steps first.

1. Write an application that on startup read commands from a directory
   : So on startup you have a command directory.
   : You open each file (in order execute the file if it is valid) then re-name the file to show it was done.
2. Modify your application to run as a continious loop.
   All the loop does is look for events in job queue.
   : if it sees them execute the job.
   : If no job there then sleep for 10 seconds.
   : On startup you just inject one job
   -> : It reads the command directory and creates a job for each file.
   -> : The file job executes the file then renames the file to show it is done.
3. Modify your service to use threading.
   : Run the event loop in one thread.
   : Use locks and semaphores so that added items to the queue is thread safe.
   : When the application starts up you start the event loop (making sure it started then inject the job (as in 2). Then just waits for the event loop to finish (it will not).
4. Add a timer thread that fires very ten seconds to check the command directory
   : All the timer should do is create a job and put it in the event queue.
   : Now you don't need to inject a job at startup its the timers job.
5. Once you have all the above running you are ready to introduce a listener that will listen on a socket for indirect commands from another application.
   : Doing all the above in one go to run the service is going to be long an error prone for a beginner. I advice you to fallow through all the steps above to get to this state then ask another question about how to do IPC.
   : So add a new thread that listens on a socket (OK this is not the best technique but this is bootstrapping a beginner). When it receives input it creates a file in the command directory then places a job in the job queue.
6. You should now be able to test your command using the command line `curl` (or `wget` command) to send files to your service.
7. Once you have it working with `curl`.
   You can write a standalone application that converts command line arguments into command files and sends them to your service.
8. Convert your application from using files to having all the information in the job object.
9. Thats it.

Comment: I know how to i/o from a file and I have experience with Boost timers. I can pretty much write this right now but I don't know how to, like, get a response code.

Comment: Console Application -> File -> Main Process
How do I go from Main Process -> Console Application (respond to the command)

Comment: You can do that by making your helper application create a file in a directory. Your service just checks the directory for command files every 10 seconds. Get that working first. Then worry about IPC.

Comment: True, I could make it create a file and send that to the main application to write it's response into.

Comment: Start here. Once it is working. Look up IPC. Trying to do all this in one go will be really buggy and hard going. Do each step above and make sure it works. There are a lot of concepts here. Event Loops/Threads/Locking/Semaphres/Commands Pattern/Sockets. Each of these is a large enough topic on its own that you need to learn.

Comment: I have experience with Sockets, Event Loops, Locking (In context of Concurrency) and Command Pattern... The reason I don't use sockets is because it's lot of code and error management for a very simple feature.